# Find in one cell, replace in different cell - Only works for one phase

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating a tool that will help with translations for a user interface.

I have a list of English phrases in Sheet "Translate" Col A which I want to compare with English Phrases from a library of translations on sheet "2052 Simplified Chinese" in Col A. When a match is found I want the cosponsoring Chinese phrase from Col B of the library sheet to be copied to Col B of "Translate" Sheet.

Searching different forums for similar problems I found the following sub which I adapted to my needs:

```
Sub Replace_From_List()

Dim cell As Range, rngFind As Range, counter As Long
Dim RefSheet As String
Dim ReplaceSheet As String

RefSheet = "2052 Simplified Chinese"
ReplaceSheet = "Translate"

'List of items to search for from Translated phases sheet column A
With Sheets(RefSheet)
    Set rngFind = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

For Each cell In rngFind
    'Search in Sheet containing phases to translate Column A
    Set Found = Sheets(ReplaceSheet).Range("A:A").Find(What:=cell.Value, _
                                                   LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                                   LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                                   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                                   MatchCase:=False)

    If Not Found Is Nothing Then
        'When a match is found, replace Sheet "Translate" column B with Sheet "2052 Simplified Chinese" Column B
        'Overwrites formulas
        Found.Offset(, 1).Value = cell.Offset(, 1).Value
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next cell

MsgBox "Replacements made: " & counter, , "Replacements Complete"

End Sub
```

However, this seems to only replace each matched phrase only once then move on to the next phrases. I need it to keep searching the whole sheet and replace each match it finds before it moves on to the next phrase.

You can see in the pic below that the value in B3 should also be in B4, the same with B18:B21

[Results from Replace_From_List() Sub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWxkw.png)

I think that I need to add another loop or change my loop parameters to do this but I'm not entirely sure what's happening.

I'm familiar with programming in C but I'm pretty much a novice with VBA.

Comment: From your description it sounds like the [vlookup](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) function in column B of sheet "Translate" should work.

Comment: Thanks, just been looking in to that and it could well be an easier method. Will give it a go if I completely fail with my current method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the FindNext method which will search for values until it returns to the original found item (though I must say I don't see why you couldnt just use VLOOKUP).

```
Sub Replace_From_List()

Dim cell As Range, rngFind As Range, counter As Long
Dim RefSheet As String
Dim ReplaceSheet As String
Dim s As String

RefSheet = "2052 Simplified Chinese"
ReplaceSheet = "Translate"

'List of items to search for from Translated phases sheet column A
With Sheets(RefSheet)
    Set rngFind = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

For Each cell In rngFind
    'Search in Sheet containing phases to translate Column A
    Set found = Sheets(ReplaceSheet).Range("A:A").Find(What:=cell.Value, _
                                                   LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                                   LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                                   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                                   MatchCase:=False)

    If Not found Is Nothing Then
        'When a match is found, replace Sheet "Translate" column B with Sheet "2052 Simplified Chinese" Column B
        'Overwrites formulas
        s = found.Address
        Do
            found.Offset(, 1).Value = cell.Offset(, 1).Value
            counter = counter + 1
            Set found = Sheets(ReplaceSheet).Range("A:A").FindNext(found)
        Loop While found.Address <> s
    End If
Next cell

MsgBox "Replacements made: " & counter, , "Replacements Complete"

End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks, there may well be much better ways of doing what I want but I am not familiar yet with many of the functions available with VBA/Excel. So I am approaching the problem from a PLC/C programming background. I had a look at vLookup, looks like It would have been better but I've started down this road now. Will probably try that though when I have more time later.